# PHP Solr Client - Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, apache, lucene, solr

I am using SOLR PHP client to query data from a solr service.  My code looks similar to the below in that I'm passing in a query to search on multiple IDs (in my case, a lot).  The problem arises for me when I'm searching for too many IDs at once.  I get a 'Request Entity Too Large' when passing in too many IDs.  Is there a way to get around this?  From what I see in various examples, the syntax seems to be 'id:1 OR id:2 OR id:3 etc.' when searching on multiple values. This there a different syntax that would reduce the size of the request being passed into the service?  e.g. In SQL we can say, 'id in (1,2,3,etc.)'.  Can we do something similar for the SOLR query?

```
<?php  
  require_once( 'SolrPHPClient/Apache/Solr/Service.php' );  
  $solr = new Apache_Solr_Service( 'localhost', '8983', '/solr' );    

  $offset = 0;
  $limit = 10;

  $queries = array(
    'id: 1 OR id: 2 OR id:3 OR id:4 OR id:5 OR id:6 or id:7 or id:8'  // in my case,       this list keeps growing and growing
    );

  foreach ( $queries as $query ) {
  $response = $solr->search( $query, $offset, $limit );

  if ( $response->getHttpStatus() == 200 ) { 
     print_r( $response->getRawResponse() );
  }
  else {
     echo $response->getHttpStatusMessage();
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: I had a similar problem but switched to another notation of the search like

 viewPermGroupId:(ANY OR 018f5984be10c58ac950f3de8223d76a OR 021132071593b65c1d9ea28d60ac57c3)

Thats a bit shorter....

Answer (score 3):

Solr supports searching through POST HTTP requests instead of GET requests which will allow you to have a much bigger query. I don't know how to enable this in the PHP client you're using.

However this is only a bandaid. The real problem is that you seem to be misusing Solr. You will likely run into other limits and performance issues, simply because Solr wasn't designed to do what you're trying to do. You wouldn't use PHP to write an operating system, right? It's the same with this.

I recommend creating a new question with the *real* issue you have that led you to run this kind of queries.

Comment: could you elaborate on the mis-usage or Solr?  The decision to use Solr to speed up database searching came from another team.  My team is the end user of this service and we simply need to integrate with it.  Needless to say, we don't know very much about Solr as we've just started mucking around with it.  I'd be interested to know how Solr is being misused, and what the real usage should be.

Comment: @ttngo: I think you should speak to the other team about this instead of asking me or stackoverflow. Stackoverflow and I are **not** part of your project. If you have specific questions about Solr do post them here (as new questions of course).

Comment: Thank you for this hint Mauricio. This solved my current comparable issue. BTW: I don´t see there a misuse of SOLR - in my situation for example I´m checking the visibility of the pages depending on group membership of the current user. Two user in my application belong to > 300 groups and thats why the query string got >16 kByte.

Comment: Who wants to know: switching to POST in SOLR PHP Client is possible with adding a parameter at the end like: 
$solr->search(utf8_encode($q), $startLimit, $pageRows, $additionalParameters, 'POST');

Answer (score 1):

Solr supports range queries, i.e. id:[1 TO 10], or id:[* TO *] to match all. Since it looks like many of your "ORs" are with respect to sequential IDs, this should help.

Comment: Thanks csjohn for the quick response.  Yes, ranges should help.  Though my values are really not in sequential order.  I only made it so in my example so that I don't have to do too much thinking ;)

Comment: @ttngo You can use the wildcard syntax to encompass some larger more general ranges too. For example id:[122 TO *] would match all documents with id greater than or equal to 122.

Comment: That is a good suggestion.  Though, my values are user selected values and they could be anything.  I will not be able determine the order or ranges of these values.

Comment: It's starting to sound to me like you're using Solr to store values like a database, rather than search. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.  The amount of data that we have in the database is so huge that doing it a direct database query takes way way too long.  We are hoping that using Solr would speed up our searches.

Comment: So you need to return data based on ID numbers specifically? How much data are we talking about here?